# How do I install mutt 1.7.0 on Xenial or Trusty?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, software-installation, mutt

My favorite command line email client has a big new version. Mutt version 1.7.0 has been released on August 18th 2016 and among other changes and improvements the developers have merged the very useful 'sidebar' patch. I am very keen to come to grips with this!

How do I install this newest version of mutt on Xenial Xerus and Trusty Tahr?

Comment: The email client?

Comment: @Anwar The very one :) Hopefully I have clarified a little in the question...

Comment: There is a PPA for it at https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/backports.

Comment: @edwinksl that could be the answer :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As one may expect, Jonathon Fernyhough has a PPA for version 1.7.0 of `mutt` for Ubuntu 16.04 (and 14.04 too) at https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/backports:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mutt
```

Comment: Note: The mentioned repo "ppa:jonathonf/backports" has backports of several more packages, not just mutt. Adding this repo and doing "apt-get update/upgrade" will update more packages than just mutt. Just saying, so you are not surprised when it happens.

Answer (score 8):

[Edwin's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/823575/61218) of using PPA is great. But if you like being adventurous You can try building from source too.

1. Download the source

   ```
   wget -c ftp://ftp.mutt.org/pub/mutt/mutt-1.7.0.tar.gz
   ```
2. Extract it and `cd` to it

   ```
   tar xf mutt-1.7.0.tar.gz
   cd mutt-1.7.0/
   ```
3. Make sure you have necessary development packages installed. I had `build-essential` installed already and needed to install `libncurses5-dev`. So do this

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential libncurses5-dev
   ```
4. Then proceed with installation. You should check the `INSTALL` file customize the build. For example you might want to use these parameters to `configure`

   - `--enable-pop` for enabling POP3 support
   - `--enable-imap` for enabling IMAP support
   - `--with-ssl` which will enable SSL support for POP and IMAP. Needs OpenSSL headers and development libraries.

   Now the typical sequence of commands. (If you want customizations, you'll need to pass the options after `./configure` like `./configure --enable-pop`.)

   ```
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

   or if you want to use `checkinstall` the last step would be

   ```
   sudo checkinstall -D make install
   ```

   the `-D` switch is used to make a debian package from installation. Check details on it in the *Addition* section.

   Mutt 1.7 should get installed.

---

**Addition:** As andrew.46 said, we can also use `checkinstall` instead of `make install`. This will give us the opportunity to remove the package with a single command and to have a debian package (if `-D` option is used), which can be used in multiple other machines to install it.

More on `checkinstall`

- [Debian Administrators article on checkinstall](https://debian-administration.org/article/147/Installing_packages_from_source_code_with_checkinstall)

Comment: Just for future reference, the following should flags should be enabled for a functional mail client:

--enable-imap
--enable-pop
--enable-smtp
--enable-sidebar
--enable-gpgme
--with-curses
--with-ssl
--with-sasl